# Dynamically saving a ranking of scores in Rails

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

New to Rails, and I want to clarify how I can dynamically update content in the database.

Specifically, I am making a Quiz project right now. A Javascript quiz checks each answer on the server side and then adds the total number of points (so 6 correct answers, a user would have 6 in the `score` column).

I then show a scoreboard to "rank" the user. Problem is, I am not really "ranking" them -- not in the way that I could later return to the `Quiz` table and see that one user finished #1, another finished #2, etc. Instead, I am organizing the `score` results by total score. So the user sees a rank based on where a user is listed, but it isn't being stored.

Here's what I am doing now.

In the Scoreboard controller, I filter the table of all Quiz results to just the scores matching the current quiz (determined by `:category`).

```
def index
 @quizzes = Quiz.where(finished: true, category: session[:category]).order(score: :desc)
end
```

In the view, I am then showing the `Quiz` results organized by their `score`.

```
 <% @quizzes.each do |Quiz| %>
   <tr>
     <td></td>
     <td><%= quiz.user.username %></td>
     <td><%= quiz.user.city %></td>
     <td><%= quiz.category %></td>
     <td><%= quiz.score %></td>
   <% end %>
 </tr>
```

So the output is a table of scores (7,6,5..).

If I added a column for `rank`, is it possible to create an integer value matching where they finished in the game? Currently, the game knows to insert scores to the corresponding user by matching `:category` in the `Quiz` model. Can the table dynamically store a "rank" for all results matching that category?

Answer (score 0):

Do you really want to store `rank` in DB or just want to render it? If you just want to render it, then you can use `.each_with_index` method instead of `.each` and render it dynamically.

But if you want to store in DB (which seems strange to me), then you've to write a small piece of code which iterate through the Quiz of that category and update rankings of everyone. Actually you to make use of background processing libraries like Sidekiq or Delayed Job. So once the controller receives quiz submission call, it'll just update the score and handover the rank updation part to background jobs.

Comment: Yes, I have rendered it before using that method. That's what I was alluding to that it's clear to the view where a player ranked, but I am not storing it anywhere. Let's say I want to show results in a different location (like have a dashboard where a user could see where they ranked in past games). I was thinking I would show the `rank` column result there for the `current_user`. If you don't think it's a good idea though, maybe I can figure out another way without background processing.

Comment: In that case you surely be able to write some code in controller to update rankings of all players who took that quiz. Background processing is just for scalability aspects.